# How to write a menu driven program in C++ without using a switch case.

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a menu driven program without using switch case but I'm not getting to a conclusion on which statement to use. Let me know if any one is having an answer.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Do you have some code you could show us?

Comment: @imulsion: It seems pretty clear to me. OP wants to be able to create menus without having to have very large switch blocks to determine what to do in what menu. Especially if menus can have nested menus (hello nested switch blocks !).

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: Not to me, it isn't. It sounds like a homework assignment, unless this user wants to provide more details. "not getting to a conclusion on which statement to use" does not sound like someone looking for design patterns. This question should receive a major edit from the OP to more clearly explain what's being asked here.

Answer (score 4):

You want to learn about the Command design pattern. It is a very good candidate for designing menu items without relying on large switch blocks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern